# Unable to set-up Online Accounts

Tags: kubuntu, kde, online-accounts

Running Kubuntu 17.04.

```
System Settings -> Online Accounts -> Create -> Google (or many others)
```

produces an error --- different errors for different services.

What is wrong here? How do I set this right?

Comment: Maybe share the errors so people can help?

Comment: And Manjaro KDE users report something similar: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-online-accounts-and-google/11409/4

Comment: @DKBose OK. That does not solve my problem. But I know that there is no solution presently. So, I will wait :) BTW, I had access to a Fedora installation earlier and I could access Google Accounts there.

Comment: Was that a KDE flavor of Fedora?

Comment: @DKBose Yes. It was.